Exporting a React component from a Nextjs application and using it directly in the DOM of another project
I'm asked to export a React component from a nextjs project and implement this component inside a blade.php file of another project. Currently I'm trying this by putting the output mode on 'export'.
next.config.js:
module.exports = {
   output: 'export',
   distDir: 'dist',
};

Then I do a next build and copy some of the code (omit html and head tags) from the generated index.html file along with the generated js files to the other project.
For now the component itself renders and works fine (except for a few warnings), but all the other html that was also inside the <body> gets removed (I would've exptected this).
Is this the way to go or are there better ways to approach this? Suggestions welcome!
